Why isn't angular momentum conserved if I take torque about the point on a frictional surface?
Lets say I have a box which is moving on a rough horizontal surface. Now if I take a point $P$ on the surface then the net torque on the box would be zero about $P$ since the force of friction acts in the line of $P$. Therefore angular momentum about the point $P$ should be conserved. But this does not happen. Why so?

Do you mean $P$ lies along the velocity vector i.e. the object is moving directly towards or away from $P$? If so the torque and angular momentum are both zero.

Ditto John Rennie. Anyway, I’m not sure what you’re question has do with conservation of angular momentum


...if I take a point $P$ on the surface then the net torque on the box would be zero about $P$ since the force of friction acts in the line of $P$.

The torque from friction applies zero torque about $P$.   But other forces are present, so we can not yet say that net torque is zero.
If the block were moving in space and we applied a force similar to friction on the bottom surface, the block would rotate forward as it slowed down, since the "frictional" force is not in line with the center of mass.
But on the rough surface, the block does not rotate.   Therefore there must be a counter-torque.   This comes from the normal force from the surface no longer acting through the center of mass.   The normal force instead moves so that the average force is now forward of the center of mass.   Since gravity and the normal are no longer in-line, they do not cancel out when considered about $P$ and provide for a change in angular momentum.
